# Java-Checking for main class

Tags: java, mainclass

I had a problem in one of my java products, in which players would run a cheat class as the main class. Is there a way in which I can check for the main class running? I've tried adding a UID but they seemed to get past it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is hardly a robust and bulletproof solution, but you could *try* looking at the thread's stack trace and ensure that your class is the last element:

```
final StackTraceElement[] stack = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();

if (! stack[stack.length-1].getClassName().equals(YourClass.class.getName()))
{
  // abort
}
```

However, there's nothing to stop someone compiling a class with the same fully qualified class name as your legitimate class and replacing your original one.

Comment: that just makes it a wee bit harder. You cannot check if they are using your class as main. The way Java works its almost always possible to spoof stuff. they only way you can maybe force things is to completly obfuscate your code and make it really hard to not use your own main class.

Comment: @Peter: to be clear, you're saying they could compile a class that has the same FQCN right? That's true ...  I agree the problem likely imposible to solve given the way Java dynamically loads and links classes.

Comment: @GregKopff How, about if they use 2 main classes, like one class is ran to search for the main class?

Comment: @Mr.Charles: I don't understand your comment - there is only 1 "main class" if you define 'main class' as the JVM entry point.

Comment: @GregKopff They are using a reflect client, in which looks for my main class. However, they run the reflect class as the main, not my main class. Sorry, if I may of cause confusion.

Comment: @Mr.Charles: in which case, `"ReflectClass"` would be at `stack[stack.length-1]` and you would know to abort.  (However, you're fighting an uphill battle which can be defeated by the process I also outline above).

Comment: @GregKopff Thanks, I'll try to add to my main class to see if it works.

Comment: even that will not help. If they make a class with same package and name as your and put it in front of yours in the classpath then their will run first bypassing your and bypassing your test for the reflect class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use something like this,

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class Checker {
  private static final String HASH_MAIN_CLASS = "Hash of your valid Main class";

  public boolean isExecutingValidMainClass() throws IOException{
     StackTraceElement[] stack = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
     String mainClassName = stack[stack.length-1].getClassName();

     String pathToMainClass = mainClassName.replaceAll("\\.", File.separator) + ".class";

     InputStream inputStream = AppMain.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(pathToMainClass);

     byte[] mainClassBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

     if(HASH_MAIN_CLASS.equals(byteArrayHash(mainClassBytes))){
       return true;
     }else{
       return false;
     }
  }

  private String byteArrayHash(byte[] byteArray){

    //Calculate hash for byte array

    //Return  hash for byte array

  }
}
```

It is not infallible, but they would have to compile a cheat Main class with the same hash that your Main class. Using an appropriate hash algorithm would be complex using a cheat Main class.

Comment: Unfortunately, this suffers from the same problem as all the other solutions discussed: it's trivial to replace the class that does the checking with a class that indicates, or to eliminate the class that _invokes_ the checker.